# Регулярное выражение для замены

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, замена

Просьба помочь составить регулярное выражение для замены, чтобы из строки

```
  <a name="soldhouse" onclick="tooltip(this, writeSold('5', 'Дуплекс'))" onmouseover="tooltip(this, writeSold('5', 'Дуплекс'))" onmouseout="hide_info(this)"><div class="genplan-house-big-sold" style="left:1261px; top:1448px;">5</div></a>
```

получилось

```
show(5 'sold', 1261, 1448);
```

для PHP / редактора

Либо какой-то другой способ (у меня есть блок из 400 объектов, нужно привести к такому виду).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если построчно, то

```
preg_match("/writeSold\('(\d+)'.*left:(\d+)px.*top:(\d+)px/",$string, $matches);
$res="show(".$matches[1].", 'solid', ".$matches[2].", ".$matches[3].");\n";
```

Замечу, что проверки на то что в строке на наличие всего что нужно нет! (т.е. либо каждый обрабатываемый $string должен быть в вашем формате, либо добавляйте анализ строки)